# How to style the direct parent in CSS? (without using Has)

Tags: html, css

Let's say that i have this HTML file:

```
<div> class="parent-x">_</div>
<div> class="parent-x">_</div>
<div> class="parent-x">_</div>
<div> class="parent-x">
    <div> class="some-child"> A child </div>
</div>
```

I want to style "parent-x" who is the direct parent to class "some-child". (without using Has since it's not supported in all browsers)

**what i have tried is:**

```
.parent-x > .some-child {  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;  
}
```

but this styles the child itself not the parent.

**I tried using "!" to select which class to be styled:**

```
 .parent-x! > .some-child {  
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;  
     }
```

But I guess it is not supported anymore

**Also I tried:**

```
.some-child < .parent {  
             display: flex;
             align-items: center;  
         }
```

But it gives me syntax error in my editor.

Comment: you would have to use :has(). `.parent-x:has(> .some-child)`

Comment: Also, please note that your markup is severely malformed, which is going to give you lots of problems.

Comment: By pure CSS you cannot go up on the tree, so you cannot access the parent.

Comment: @AlexanderNied it's not really my code, it is a technical debt. But do you have any good suggestions about it?

Comment: @epascarello isn't there another way other than using has?

Comment: @epascarello my question says "Without using has" so it is not really a duplicate.

Comment: It's a dupe. Every possible answer is there.

Comment: As the dupe states, [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) _is the_ "parent selector" that front end developers were wishing for for years; if you want a CSS-only solution that is your best (and pretty much only) bet.  If you can manually add a class to parents that contain the specific children, or use JavaScript, then you have some other options.

Comment: `parent-x! > .some-child` was never supported. It's just an early proposal of what later became `:has()`

Comment: There is no way to go up other than has(). If you can't use has, then you need to use JavaScript.